# R loop ascending variable names

Tags: r, loops, variables, names

I am trying to create a loop over variable names in R. It should do the square root of the sum of both variables. I have this up to now:

Variable names are x1,y1, x2,y2, ... x30,y30 (all in one matrix, matrix$x1, matrix$x2)

```
x1 <- c(2,2,2,3,1,2,4,6,1)
y1 <- c(5,4,3,3,4,2,1,6,3)
x2 <- c(8,2,7,3,1,2,2,2,4)
y2 <- c(1,3,3,3,1,2,4,3,7)
x3 <- c(4,4,1,2,4,6,3,2,3)
y3 <- c(1,2,3,3,1,2,4,6,6)
matrix <- cbind(x1,y1,x2,y3,x3,y3)

for(i in 1:30){
    result[[i]]  <- sqrt(x`i' + y`i')
}
```

What can I do?

Comment: What you're trying to do is difficult because you made the mistake of creating 60 separate, free-standing variables, rather than putting them in a single data structure like a list or a matrix. For example, a a two column matrix, or a list of length 2 vectors.

Comment: It is, I changed it in the description! Sorry for the unclearities!

Comment: That's still a fairly awkward data structure for what you're trying to do. Still, it's at least possible by subsetting by pasting together column names. i.e. something like `matrix[,paste0("x",i)]`.

Comment: could you provide an example of your matrix?

Comment: here you go, just simple variables, it goes up to 30 though

Comment: @tobias A technicality with your description: `matrix$x1` cannot refer to column `x1` in the matrix; it works for a data frame. If your data is strictly a matrix, you would need something like `matrix[,"x1"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example matrix:

```
dat <- matrix(1:300, ncol = 60)
colnames(dat) <- paste0(rep(c("x", "y"), 30), rep(1:30, each = 2))
```

And here's a solution:

```
for (i in 1:30) {
  assign(paste0("result", i), sqrt( dat[, paste0("x", i)] + dat[, paste0("y", i)] ) )
  dat <- cbind(dat, get(paste0("result", i)))
}
colnames(dat)[61:90] <- paste0("result", 1:30)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the original question looked like but your code now seems fine except that you need to use `paste()` to construct the variable names and `get()` to get them.

```
 for(i in 1:30){
    result[[i]]  <- sqrt(get(paste('x',i,sep='')) + get(paste('y',i,sep='')))
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that format is a little awkward but still managable. We look for the columnnames having the current 'i' in their name and calculate the sqrt of their sums.

```
result <- vector()
for (i in 1:3){
  result[i] <- sqrt(sum(matrix[,which(grepl(i,colnames(matrix)))]))
}
```

using your data gives:

```
> result
[1] 7.348469 7.615773 7.549834
```